# Facebook Connect: "post-add URL" being loaded in popup window. How can I stop?

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook connect setup which signs the user in using FB.Connect.requireSession(), and gets some permissions using FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog()

The problem: when the user adds my application for the first time, instead of closing the FB Connect window and setting cookies, it loads the "post-add URL" in the FB connect popup window! This is surely wrong

If the user has already added the application, it works as expected. Since the post-add URL has now been removed from application settings, how can I stop this behaviour, and make the user sign in clearly even if they have just added the app?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you comment and vote up the open Facebook bug report for this - http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12260 .